# can't show a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm newbie to jquery and I know that my question is simple. I would like to display a form.
Here is my jquery function:

```
function display_form(s_date)
  {    
        $('#addEvent').show();    
  }
```

Here is how it is called :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
            {   
                date_format = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    display_form(date_format);
                    return false;
                 },
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myLogin%40gmail.com/public/basic'

    });
});
```

It doesn't work. When I click on a day, nothing happens.
I tried the code (directly display_form without the call) on http://jsfiddle.net/PytEU/ and it worked.
Maybe someone have the answer?
Thank you for your help

Here is my form :

```
<div>
<form id="addEvent" action="" method="post" >
 // my form
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: what I don't understand is that when I surround .show() by try catch it does not catch the error.

Comment: whhere is "#calendar" in your code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the form in the same file that the jquery function and it works. I don't know if it is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

In your css file

```
#formHolder {
   display: none;
}
```

Set the div holding the form to have the id above ...

```
<div id="formHolder">
    <form id="addEvent" action="" method="post" >
         // my form
     </form>
</div>
```

jquery for showing the form should be something like (where .clickme is the class of the clickable element such as a link etc.)

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#formHolder).show('fast');
});
```

Comment: Should I necessarily have a clickable element?

Comment: It depends how you want the page to perform, having a click element ensures that the form will only appear if the page element with the .clickMe class in this example is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kam2001/hNC66/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addEvent").show('slow')
});      


$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

  dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
      {   
      date_format = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      display_form(date_format);
      return false;
      },
  events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myLogin%40gmail.com/public/basic'

});
});
```

Comment: could you tell me please what do you put in display_form? Because I coded on jsFiddle and it works.However .show() still not working for me.  I tried this :  <div id="addEvent" style="display:none"> MY FORM</div> and I added   $("#addEvent").css("display", "block"); 
in display_form function (before calling show()) . When I click on a day, nothing happens :/

Comment: Hi, i am not sure if you want help on making the calender function work or just to show/hide the form. the code i previously provided is just to show the form if it is hidden. Are you using the calender script from here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/